# How does the OS detect numbers and strings?

Tags: string, memory-management, operating-system, numbers

If we have a string `"A"` and a number 65, since they look identical in memory, how does the OS know which is the string and which is the number?

Another question - assume that a program allocates some memory (say, one byte).  How does the OS remember where that memory has been allocated?

Comment: Your #1 doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @pyroscope- I think it's actually a very reasonable question.  It's not obvious how the computer knows to treat different variables as having different types when they all look the same at the end of the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these details are handled by the operating system.  They're handled by user programs.

For your first question, internally in memory there is absolutely no distinction between the character 'A' and the numeric value 65 (assuming, of course, that you're just looking at one byte of data).  The difference arises when you see how those bits are interpreted by the program.  For example, if the user program tries to print the string to the screen, it will probably make some system call to the OS to ask the OS to print the character.  In that case, the code in the OS consists of a series of assembly instructions to replicate those bits somewhere in the display device.  The display is then tasked with rendering a set of appropriate pixels to draw the character 'A.'  In other words, at no point did the program ever "know" that the value was an 'A.'  Instead, the hardware simply pushed around bits which controlled another piece of code that ultimately was tasked with turning those bits into pixels.

For your second question, that really depends on the memory manager.  There are many ways for a program to allocate memory and know where it's stored.  I'm not fully sure I understand what you're asking, but I believe that this answer should be sufficient:

1. At the OS level, the OS kernel doesn't even know that the byte was allocated.  Instead, the OS just allocates giant blocks of memory for the user program to use as it runs.  When the program terminates, all that memory is reclaimed.
2. At the program level, most programs contain a *memory manager,* a piece of code tasked with allocating and divvying up that large chunk of memory into smaller pieces that can then be used by the program.  This usually keeps track of allocated memory as a list of "chunks," where each chunk of memory is treated as a doubly-linked list of elements.  Each chunk is usually annotated with information indicating that it's in use and how large the chunk is, which allows the memory manager to reclaim the memory once it's freed.
3. At the user code level, when you ask for memory, you typically store it in a pointer to keep track of where the memory is.  This is just a series of bytes in memory storing the address, which the OS and memory manager never look at unless instructed to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Is there any good resource that explain it! I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

No. 2 - the system keeps a record of all allocations (of a certain process) and can thus remove them e.g. when the process terminates. I propose you read a book on operating system priciples (e.g. Tanenbaum's "Modern Operating Systems").

Comment: Isn't it more like operation system allocates a chunk of memory (e.g Virtual Memory) for a process and it is up to that process how to handle it instead of operating system recording the allocations?

Comment: There are several layers of management here, the virtual memory map is something in the OS (sbrk in *nix), while the pages given to the process are then handled by whatever the application uses (e.g. some form of malloc, or Java GC).

Answer (score 1):

1. The character 'A' and the integer number 65 are stored the same way (atleast on 32bit systems) in memory.  The string "A" however is stored differently, and that can depend on the system or the programming language.  Take for example C which will stored strings as essentially an array of the characters followed by the null character.
2. Operating Systems use memory managers to keep track of which process are using which parts of memory.

Answer (score 0):

1. For a computer, a string is a number. A simpliest example would be an ASCII table where for every letter there is a number attached. So if you're familiar with C, you could write `printf("%c", 0x65)` and actually get a `A` instead of number. Hope that made sense.
2. OS don't remember the location of the memory the program has allocated. That's what [pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29) are for!

Answer (score -1):

1. The 'OS' applies an algorithm, which will look something like: "if every character in the string is a number, then the string is a number", and gets more complicated for decimals, +/-, etc!
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation!